# Return rows based on multiple columns

Tags: sql

I am a novice Microsoft Query user.  I have a table with info like

```
ckno    ckdate    type  
123     12/1/12     PV  
654     11/6/12     EP
123     12/14/12    EP
852     01/3/13     PV
```

I want to return all the rows with a type of PV or EP where the ck# are the same (rows 1 and 3). What does the sql look like for this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, which should allow you to have multiple differences in type:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM SomeTable t
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable x 
        WHERE x.ckno = t.ckno AND x.type <> t.type)
```

Comment: I should point out that if [type] can be NULL, then you'd want to be sure to handle that as well (ISNULL around your x.type and t.type is presumably the best way).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable T
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT ckno 
                FROM YourTable
                WHERE [type] IN ('PV','EP')
                AND ckno = T.ckno
                GROUP BY ckno
                HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```